# Livewire + AlpineJS: Using x-data as wire:click param

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a Laravel Blade template which has an AlpineJS div defined like this:

```
<div x-data="{ id: 2 }">
   ...
   <button type="button" wire:click="deleteAddress(id)">Button</button>
</div>
```

What I want is somehow "pass" that `id` variable to the wire:click call.

The above code throws an `Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined` in my JS console.
Any ideas? Just starting with the TALL stack and I do not know the optimal workflows yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js under "*Sharing State Between Livewire And Alpine: @entangle*", does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Ended up with `@entangle`, linking a property within the component to the AlpineJS code.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Alpine click listener with the magic $wire, as described here:
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js

This way you'll stay "inside" Alpine, but with access to your Livewire component method. So it's going to be:

```
<div x-data="{ id: 2 }">
   ...
   <button type="button" @click="$wire.deleteAddress(id)">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wire:key to the same div as the x-data.

```
<div wire:key="id" x-data="{ id: 2 }">
   ...
   <button type="button" wire:click="deleteAddress(id)">Button</button>
</div>
```

I think this is because Livewire only updates what is changing. And the x-data div is the top div of an alpine component. so if you add the id as wire:key to the div that contains the x-data then this div will also get updated and it will rerun the alpine component.